# .htaccess rewrite urls from subdomain to parent directory

Tags: .htaccess

This seems a specific scenario. When someone visits `sub.domain.com`, webserver reads `.htaccess` from `/public_html/sub` folder in root. I want, anyone who visits to that `sub.domain.com`, served pages were from `/public_html` and not not from `/sub` folder.  How to achieve that?

p.s. I guess in the case of Subdomains, the `.htaccess` in the `public_html` is not read at all in this case. So, I have to handle from `/sub` folder.

I know this is a small play, but something like this ?

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)?$ %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/../
```

or can `mod_alias` do any help?

Comment: Do you have current rule which is picking content from sub directory!

Comment: I have not current.. I need subdomain to be directed by root's htaccess.  and that htaccess is : http://pastebin.com/raw/wkhEGnGg